# Hahn-Banach separation theorem where one of the sets is neither open nor closed.

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $X$ be a convex set in the real Hilbert space with countable basis, $0\notin X$.
Is it true that there is a hyperplane containing $0$ and disjoint with $X$?

For an open $X$ this would be a direct consequence of the Hahn-Banach separation theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the plane, let
$$
X = \{(x,y): x>0\} \cup \{(0,y):y>0\} .
$$
Note $X$ is convex, and $(0,0) \notin X$.  Now try to find a line through $(0,0)$ disjoint from $X$.

What you can find is the line $x=0$, such that $X$ is in the half-plane $x \ge 0$ and $(0,0)$ is in the opposite half-plane $x \le 0$.

Comment: Thanks, that answers the question. The follow up will be can you always find a hyperplane such that $X$ is in one closed half-space, and $0$ is in the other? As you've pointed out you can do it in your example.

Comment: @freddy: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn–Banach_theorem#Geometric_Hahn–Banach_theorem would require that $X$ has nonempty interior.